# Continuous fitted values for a categorical predictors in a mixed effects model and subsequent boot strapping

Tags: bootstrap, diagnostic

I have undertaken a reciprocal turf transplant in a blocked experimental design, where turfs have been moved in an out of high use areas with corresponding controls. I have measured the change in nutrient availability over time in response to the treatment. Because I am interested in the specific responses (i.e. increase in use and decrease in use) I sub-setted the data and I have built a very simple mixed effects model: nutrient~treatment + (1 | Block). My actual question has two parts:

1. When I examine the residuals vs fitted values for the increased use sub-setted data the fitted values look continuous, however, for the decreased use data they appear in two straight lines (which is what I expected). I can not see any differences in the the models and the data is all from the original data set, so should all be the same. Is there any obvious reason why this might occur?

[image: Increase in use, with fitted values appearing continuous]
[image: Decrease in use, with fitted values appearing in two lines]

2. I am using bootstrapping to extract confidence intervals and p-values from my models (model as above). I am using the pbkrtest and when I run the bootmer function for some of the data sets I get 50 or more warnings, which fall into three different types:
3. Unable to evaluate scaled gradient
4. Model failed to converge: degenerate Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
5. Convergence code 3 from bobyga: bobyga -- a trust region step failed to reduce q

I was wondering if anyone can tell me what these mean and how trustworthy this makes the final outputs? (Again the only difference I can see between the models that do not come up with these warnings and those that do is the spread of the fitted values).

Any help or shoves in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.